# How do I change the default wordpress navigation header that comes with my theme?

Tags: menus

THis questions is in general and applies to all themes. I would like to change the design by creating my own custom navigation bar and then coding it into my wordpresss site. I am a complete newbie and if anyone can please provide some instructions on how to do this it would be very appreciated!

This is the navigation bar I would like to change: www.jacobicoffee.com

Comment: Welcome to WPSE! Can you please provide more specific information regarding what changes you want to make to the navigation menu? I suspect that this question is going to be primarily CSS-related (which would be out of scope), but I'm hoping you can clarify.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the theme is using [wp_nav_menu](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_menu) You should be able to find where the menu is being pulled in (most likely your header).

The line you are looking for is going to look something like this
`<?php wp_nav_menu( array('menu' => 'Project Nav' )); ?>`

Once you find it create a [child theme](http://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Development#Child_Themes) then either remove the current menu and create your own or move it to the location you would like.

You may also be able to just style it was CSS.

Because most themes integrate the menu in different ways there is no way to provide instructions without knowing the theme you are using.